# JSXGraph in Moodle Formulas with two boards: Binding to input fields not working

Tags: moodle, jsxgraph

I have created a Moodle Formulas questions in the field of kinematics with two boards. While I managed to get simpler questions with only one board to work flawlessly, the problem with this question is that the bound values are not inserted into formula's input entry fields. Consequently, the student cannot submit an answer because, effectively, nothing has been filled out. The rest of the question works though, as can be seen when the correct answers are filled in the question's preview.

I provide a Moodle XML file to make it easier to reproduce the problem: [questions_formulas_JSXGraph_2boards.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xd7dz8syclsymz/questions_formulas_JSXGraph_2boards.xml?dl=0)
You need a current version of Moodle with `JSXGraph` filter and question type `Formulas` installed.

The main JSXGraph code is this:

```
<jsxgraph width="400" height="300" numberOfBoards="2" ext_formulas>

// JavaScript code to create the construction.
var jsxCode = function (question) {
  
  // Import final coordinates after submission
  var x0={x0};
  var t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3;
  [t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3] = 
  question.getAllValues([1,2,3 , 1,2,3 , x0,x0,x0 ]);
  
  JXG.Options.point.infoboxDigits = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeX = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeY = 0.1;
  
  // Create boards
  var brd0 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(BOARDID0, { 
    boundingbox: [-1, 11, 12, -11], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: 't in s',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [-0, 15], anchorX: 'right'} },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: 'x in m',      
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [+15, -0]} } },
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false 
    });
    
  var brd1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(BOARDID1, { 
    boundingbox: [-1, 3.5, 12, -3.5], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: 't in s',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [-0, 15], anchorX: 'right'} },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: 'v_x in m/s',      
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [+15, -0]} } },
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false
    });
      
  // Board brd0 needs to be updated when changes in brd1 occur
  brd1.addChild(brd0);
  
  // Attributes for points and lines
  function attrPfix(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: true, visible: false, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr}; 
  }
  function attrPmov(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: question.isSolved, snapToGrid: true, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  function attrPsma(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {visible: true, withLabel: false, color:'#4285F4', size: 1};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  const attrLine = {borders: {strokeColor:'#4285F4', strokeWidth: 3} };
  const attrGlid = {visible:false};


  // Define lines and points on brd1
  brd1.suspendUpdate();
  var lV0 = brd1.create('segment', [[0,-10], [0,10]], {visible:false}),
      lV3 = brd1.create('segment', [[-10,0], [20,0]], {visible:false});
  var pV0 = brd1.create('glider', [0, v1, lV0], attrPmov({name: "pV0"}) ),
      pV1 = brd1.create('point', [t1, v2], attrPmov({name: "pV1"}) ),
      pV2 = brd1.create('point', [t2, v3], attrPmov({name: "pV2"}) ),
      pV3 = brd1.create('glider', [t3, 0, lV3], attrPmov({name: "pV3"}) ),
      pV01 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV1)", "Y(pV0)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV12 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV2)", "Y(pV1)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV23 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV3)", "Y(pV2)"], attrPsma() )  ;
  brd1.create('polygonalchain', [ pV0, pV01, pV1, pV12, pV2, pV23, pV3 ], attrLine);
  brd1.unsuspendUpdate();

  // Define lines and points on brd1
  // Q: Is it necessary/beneficial/wrong to suspendUpdate here?
  brd0.suspendUpdate();
  var lX1 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV1.X();},-10], [function(){return pV1.X();},10]], attrGlid),
      lX2 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV2.X();},-10], [function(){return pV2.X();},10]], attrGlid),
      lX3 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV3.X();},-10], [function(){return pV3.X();},10]], attrGlid);
  var pX0 = brd0.create('point', [0, x0], attrPsma({fixed: true}) ),
      pX1 = brd0.create('glider', [t1, x1, lX1], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX2 = brd0.create('glider', [t2, x2, lX2], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX3 = brd0.create('glider', [t3, x3, lX3], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) );
  brd0.create('polygonalchain', [ pX0, pX1, pX2, pX3 ], attrLine);
  brd0.unsuspendUpdate();

  // Q: Are these updates necessary?
  brd0.update();
  brd1.update();

  // Whenever the construction is altered the values of the points are sent to formulas.
  question.bindInput(0, () => { return pV1.X(); });
  question.bindInput(1, () => { return PV2.X(); });
  question.bindInput(2, () => { return pV3.X(); });
  question.bindInput(3, () => { return pV1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(4, () => { return pV2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(5, () => { return PV3.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(6, () => { return pX1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(7, () => { return pX2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(8, () => { return pX3.Y(); });
  };
  
  // Execute the JavaScript code.
  new JSXQuestion(BOARDID0, jsxCode, allowInputEntry=true);
  
</jsxgraph>
```

Is it possible that the problem is caused because the board ids are not properly handed over in

```
new JSXQuestion(BOARDID0, jsxCode, allowInputEntry=true);
```

Besides this problem, I would like to understand JSXGraph a bit better:

1. Is it somehow possible to arrange multiple boards with respect to each other? That is, above, below, right aligned, centered etc.
2. Does it make a difference whether boards are initialized as ‘const’ or ‘var’?
3. Is it necessary/beneficial/wrong to suspend and unsuspend board updates in the example above case?
4. Are the manual update commands in the code necessary/beneficial/useless?
5. Are there any obvious lapses in my coding or usage of JSXGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now had the time to look at your problem and I was able to expand the Moodle filter. As of the new version *v1.1.0-for3.10*, several boards are also supported in formulas. You can find detailed instructions on how to use it and what to consider here [on GitHub](https://github.com/jsxgraph/moodleformulas_jsxgraph#insert-more-than-one-board-into-a-question).

The new version of the plugin can be downloaded in the [Plugins Directory](https://moodle.org/plugins/pluginversion.php?id=23188).

I took the liberty of modifying your example from above and it works for me:

```
<jsxgraph width="400" height="300" numberOfBoards="2" ext_formulas>

// JavaScript code to create the construction.
var jsxCode = function (question) {
  
  // Import final coordinates after submission
  var x0={x0};
  var t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3;
  [t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3] = 
  question.getAllValues([1,2,3 , 1,2,3 , x0,x0,x0 ]);
  
  JXG.Options.point.infoboxDigits = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeX = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeY = 0.1;
  
  // Create boards
  var brds = question.initBoards( [
  { // attribs for BOARDID0 
    boundingbox: [-1, 11, 12, -11], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: 't in s',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [-0, 15], anchorX: 'right'} },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: 'x in m',      
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [+15, -0]} } },
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false 
    },
    { // attribs for BOARDID1 
    boundingbox: [-1, 3.5, 12, -3.5], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: 't in s',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [-0, 15], anchorX: 'right'} },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: 'v_x in m/s',      
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [+15, -0]} } },
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false
    }
  ] );

  var brd0 = brds[0];
  var brd1 = brds[1];
  console.log(brd0, brd1);
      
  // Board brd0 needs to be updated when changes in brd1 occur
  question.addChildsAsc();
  /* not needed anymore
    brd1.addChild(brd0);
  */
  
  // Attributes for points and lines
  function attrPfix(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: true, visible: false, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr}; 
  }
  function attrPmov(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: question.isSolved, snapToGrid: true, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  function attrPsma(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {visible: true, withLabel: false, color:'#4285F4', size: 1};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  const attrLine = {borders: {strokeColor:'#4285F4', strokeWidth: 3} };
  const attrGlid = {visible:false};


  // Define lines and points on brd1
  brd1.suspendUpdate();
  var lV0 = brd1.create('segment', [[0,-10], [0,10]], {visible:false}),
      lV3 = brd1.create('segment', [[-10,0], [20,0]], {visible:false});
  var pV0 = brd1.create('glider', [0, v1, lV0], attrPmov({name: "pV0"}) ),
      pV1 = brd1.create('point', [t1, v2], attrPmov({name: "pV1"}) ),
      pV2 = brd1.create('point', [t2, v3], attrPmov({name: "pV2"}) ),
      pV3 = brd1.create('glider', [t3, 0, lV3], attrPmov({name: "pV3"}) ),
      pV01 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV1)", "Y(pV0)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV12 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV2)", "Y(pV1)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV23 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV3)", "Y(pV2)"], attrPsma() )    ;
  brd1.create('polygonalchain', [ pV0, pV01, pV1, pV12, pV2, pV23, pV3 ], attrLine);
  brd1.unsuspendUpdate();

  // Define lines and points on brd1
  // Q: Is it necessary/beneficial/wrong to suspendUpdate here?
  // A: It can be beneficial if you use a lot of objects. In this case the benefit is not worth mentioning, I think.
  brd0.suspendUpdate();
  var lX1 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV1.X();},-10], [function(){return pV1.X();},10]], attrGlid),
      lX2 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV2.X();},-10], [function(){return pV2.X();},10]], attrGlid),
      lX3 = brd0.create('line', [[function(){return pV3.X();},-10], [function(){return pV3.X();},10]], attrGlid);
  var pX0 = brd0.create('point', [0, x0], attrPsma({fixed: true}) ),
      pX1 = brd0.create('glider', [t1, x1, lX1], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX2 = brd0.create('glider', [t2, x2, lX2], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX3 = brd0.create('glider', [t3, x3, lX3], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) );
  brd0.create('polygonalchain', [ pX0, pX1, pX2, pX3 ], attrLine);
  brd0.unsuspendUpdate();

  // Q: Are these updates necessary?
  /* not with the new version
    brd0.update();
    brd1.update();
  */

  /* not necessary anymore
    question.board = brd0;
  */

  // Whenever the construction is altered the values of the points are sent to formulas.
  question.bindInput(0, () => { return pV1.X(); });
  question.bindInput(1, () => { return pV2.X(); }); // typo here
  question.bindInput(2, () => { return pV3.X(); });
  question.bindInput(3, () => { return pV1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(4, () => { return pV2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(5, () => { return pV3.Y(); }); // typo here
  question.bindInput(6, () => { return pX1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(7, () => { return pX2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(8, () => { return pX3.Y(); });
  };
  
  // Execute the JavaScript code.
  new JSXQuestion(BOARDIDS, jsxCode, allowInputEntry=true); // use BOARDIDS here!!
  
</jsxgraph>
```

I've already answered the other questions in the code.

I hope I could help you!

Greetings, Andreas

Comment: P.S. The code precheck errors will be fixed in the next filter version, when we release a new JSXGraph version.

Comment: Sorry, for replying so late... Thanks so much, it's fantastic you managed to extend the filter so quickly. Also thanks a lot for directly applying the changes to my code. Just two more questions: 
1) Is it somehow possible to arrange multiple boards with respect to each other? That is, above, below, right aligned, centered etc. 
2) Does it make a difference whether boards are initialized as ‘const’ or ‘var’?

Comment: Hi!
1) It is possible to control the size of the boards by attributes in the tag. For example, the specification of `width =" 500,200 "height =" 500,200 "` ensures that the first board is 500x500px and the second 200x200px. If fewer values are given than the number of boards, the first value is used as the standard. Anything that is also possible in css (rem,%, ...) can be used as units here. By default, all boards are surrounded by the css class `.jsxgraph-boards`. The standards set here can be overwritten with simple css.

Comment: See https://github.com/jsxgraph/moodle-filter_jsxgraph#jsxgraph-tag-attributes

Comment: 2) Have a look at chapter "Constant Objects can Change" on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp

Comment: So I guess you can set the dimensions, but not how two or more boxes are glued together. I am asking because I have seen a very nice example where several diagrams are organized neatly (three small ones in the top row, and a single one in the bottom row, as far as I remember).

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but what about giving the first three width 33%, the last 100%?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is correct that our filter in combination with formulas does not work correctly with multiple boards. At the moment, only one board ID is transferred to the JSXQuestion object and thus and thus it (and formulas) does not know anything about the second board. That is also one of the problems your example raises.

In addition, the boards actually have to be initialized with the JSXQuestion.initBoard() method for the bindInput() method to work. In the end, that's the root problem why your example doesn't work.

I will dedicate myself to this issue after the Christmas holidays and will be releasing a new version of the Moodle filter in January. Maybe there will be something new from JSXGraph by then, too.

Unfortunately, I can't offer you a dirty hack until then, as it requires a few basic changes to the filter.

I hope to be able to tell you more in January.
Have a nice Christmas and stay healthy!

Andreas

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! I have been eagerly waiting for getting this question to work. It will be great to be able to use multiple boards in Formulas. Btw, the whole project is amazing, and I am stoked about leveraging it and increase the usefulness of formative and summative Moodle activities for my students. Merry Christmas to you and stay healthy, too!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness sake, I post my final version of the JSXGraph code for a Formulas question based on Andreas' solution. My final touches were to

1. make the axis labels use LaTeX,
2. use the event handler `.on('drag', ...)` for two-way updates between the diagrams instead of using `question.addChildsAsc()`.

Here is the final code:

```
<jsxgraph width="400" height="300" numberOfBoards="2" ext_formulas>

// JavaScript code to create the construction.
var jsxCode = function (question) {
  
  // Import final coordinates after submission
  var x0={x0};
  var t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3;
  [t1,t2,t3 , v1,v2,v3 , x1,x2,x3] = 
  question.getAllValues([1,2,3 , 1,2,3 , x0,x0,x0 ]);
  
  JXG.Options.point.infoboxDigits = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeX = 1;
  JXG.Options.point.snapSizeY = 0.1;
  
  // Attributes for points and lines
  function attrPfix(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: true, visible: false, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr}; 
  }
  function attrPmov(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {fixed: question.isSolved, snapToGrid: true, withLabel: false};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  function attrPsma(addAttr={}) {
    const attr = {visible: true, withLabel: false, color:'#4285F4', size: 1};
    return { ...attr, ...addAttr};
  }
  const attrLine = {borders: {strokeColor:'#4285F4', strokeWidth: 3} };
  const attrGlid = {visible:false};


  // Create boards
  var brds = question.initBoards( [
  { // attribs for BOARDID0 
    boundingbox: [-1, 12, 13, -11], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: '$$t\\;\\mathrm{(s)}$$',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [10, 26], anchorX: 'right', parse: false, fontSize: 12 } },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: '$$x\\;\\mathrm{(m)}$$',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [10, 15], parse: false, fontSize: 12 } } },
      zoom: {enabled:false, wheel: false}, pan: {enabled:false, needTwoFingers: false},
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false 
    },
    { // attribs for BOARDID1 
    boundingbox: [-1, 3.8, 13, -3.5], axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {withLabel: true, name: '$$t\\;\\mathrm{(s)}$$',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [10, 26], anchorX: 'right', parse: false, fontSize: 12 } },
      y: {withLabel:true, name: '$$v_x\\;\\mathrm{(m/s)}$$',
          label: {position: 'rt', offset: [10, 15], parse: false, fontSize: 12 } } },
      zoom: {enabled:false, wheel: false}, pan: {enabled:false, needTwoFingers: false},
      showCopyright: false, showNavigation: false
    }
  ] );

  var brd0 = brds[0];
  var brd1 = brds[1];
  // console.log(brd0, brd1);

  // Board brd0 needs to be updated when changes in brd1 occur
  // question.addChildsAsc();
  

  // Define lines and points on brd1
  var pV1 = brd1.create('point',  [t1, v1], attrPmov({name: "pV1"}) ),
      pV2 = brd1.create('point',  [t2, v2], attrPmov({name: "pV2"}) ),
      pV3 = brd1.create('point',  [t3, v3], attrPmov({name: "pV3"}) ),
      pV01 = brd1.create('point', [0, "Y(pV1)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV12 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV1)", "Y(pV2)"], attrPsma() ),
      pV23 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV2)", "Y(pV3)"], attrPsma() )    ;
      pV34 = brd1.create('point', ["X(pV3)", 0], attrPsma() )    ;
  brd1.create('polygonalchain', [ pV01, pV1, pV12, pV2, pV23, pV3, pV34 ], attrLine);
  

  // Define lines and points on brd0
  var pX0 = brd0.create('point', [0, x0], attrPsma({fixed: true}) ),
      pX1 = brd0.create('point', [t1, x1], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX2 = brd0.create('point', [t2, x2], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) ),
      pX3 = brd0.create('point', [t3, x3], attrPmov({face: 'diamond'}) );
  brd0.create('polygonalchain', [ pX0, pX1, pX2, pX3 ], attrLine);
  

  // Define dependencies
  pV1.on('drag', function() { pX1.moveTo([this.X(), pX1.Y()], 0); });
  pV2.on('drag', function() { pX2.moveTo([this.X(), pX2.Y()], 0); });
  pV3.on('drag', function() { pX3.moveTo([this.X(), pX3.Y()], 0); });
  pX1.on('drag', function() { pV1.moveTo([this.X(), pV1.Y()], 0); });
  pX2.on('drag', function() { pV2.moveTo([this.X(), pV2.Y()], 0); });
  pX3.on('drag', function() { pV3.moveTo([this.X(), pV3.Y()], 0); });
  

  // Whenever the construction is altered the values of the points are sent to formulas.
  question.bindInput(0, () => { return pV1.X(); });
  question.bindInput(1, () => { return pV2.X(); });
  question.bindInput(2, () => { return pV3.X(); });
  question.bindInput(3, () => { return pV1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(4, () => { return pV2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(5, () => { return pV3.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(6, () => { return pX1.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(7, () => { return pX2.Y(); });
  question.bindInput(8, () => { return pX3.Y(); });
  };
  
  // Execute the JavaScript code.
  new JSXQuestion(BOARDIDS, jsxCode, allowInputEntry=false); // use BOARDIDS here!!
  
</jsxgraph>
```

Comment: Very nice! Just one question: Can we at the Research Center for Mobile Learning with Digital Media continue to use your example for further training, presentations and publications?

Comment: Yes, gladly. I am very grateful for the help you have provided and would be happy to give back in some way. I thinks I have also made some other nice Formula questions. If you are interested, just tell me how best to share them with you.

Comment: That would be very good! You can find my contact information in almost every file in the filter under the copyright information.